# How to call one activity from another activity within a Tab Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i use compose email activity in tabView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732999/how-can-i-use-compose-email-activity-in-tabview)

I want to call Email compose activity in a Tab.
How can i do that?

There are Two Package.

com.demo and com.demo1. Tab Activity is in com.demo and I want to call another activity from com.demo1 in Tab Activity in com.demo. How can i do that?

Comment: My code is generate Error. Error is 03-16 12:04:09.132: E/AndroidRuntime(312): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.email (with uid 10011) to be run in process android.process.acore (with uid 10001)

Comment: Why you asked same question again?

Comment: First Question is for call compose email activity in Tab Activity.Second one is for call Activity from one package to another package in Tab activity.Do you have Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composing an email will be an intent. This article helps you to call an [intent](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/12/05/tabs-with-intents/) from tabs.

And also this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/) will help you to create email intent.

Comment: i want to call different package activity in tab.

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.DEMO_MAIL");
  //intent.putExtra("hello", "Hi");
  intent.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.setup.DemoActivity");
  //startActivity(intent);

  StickyTabs.setTab(intent, TAB_INDEX_MESSAGE_LOG);
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Message") 
                .setIndicator(getString(R.string.messagetab),
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qs_logger_message_ic))
                .setContent(intent));

Comment: i already do that what ever link you send to me.

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9747907/1160207

Thanks..